# An adjective meaning that someone's act in a very kind, unexpected way

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for an adjective that means that someone's act in a very kind, unexpected way.

Few examples:

1. You cold-mail a very famous, busy person and ask him to meet for a coffee, and he replies with "sure, is [some date, some time] ok?"
2. You're in a foregin country, can't find your way to some destination, and then someone approaches you and spends the next *15 minutes* to make sure you understand how to get there.
3. You're over-70 and with certain health conditions, so you're self-isolated at home to prevent yourself from catching the coronavirus, and your neighbour goes to the grocery store *every day* to get things for you whenever needed.

Can the one being helped in each of these 3 scenarios react with "thank you so much, this is so ***unobvious***"?
The sound of it doesn't feel right to me, so I'm looking for another word.
Also thought about ***nontrivial***, but still, it doesn't sound right.

What's the right word here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Generous** could work. From M-W:

> **[generous](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/generous)**: characterized by a noble or kindly spirit : magnanimous, kindly

Your example:

> *Thank you so much. This is so **generous** of you.*

**Generous** *in this context* carries with it an air of unexpectedness, as one often uses it to characterize an act of some kind that exceeds expectations -- that is beyond the norm. In addition to being a word you would actually use in the situations you've provided, it works with all three. **Kind** would also work, but I assume you're looking for another word.

Answer (score 0):

You might use "**Godsend**" as likening the act to an answer to prayer - truly kind and helpful and seemingly unexpected as coming "just in time".

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/godsend

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering if you're looking for "gracious" (adjective) or "graciously" (adverb). [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/gracious):

> ```
> Courteous, kind, and pleasant. 
> ‘smiling and gracious in defeat’
> ```